# View Model object property not binding when posting to controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view

This is messing my head for hours now. if I use POCO it is not binding if I don't like my taxid.it binds it back to controller.

```
This is my view model

    public class testVM
    {
       public string selectedid {get;set;}
       public string taxid {get;set;}

     }
```

This is my view

```
@using VMNameSpace
@model testVM

/*tried this one too
@using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "", FormMethod.Post,new {model = Model }))
*/
@using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.selectedid) <-- does not bind

   //tried this one too
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.selectedid) <-- does not bind

   @html.TextBox("model.taxid") <-- this binds

}
```

this is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(testVM model)
{ 
       return View();
}
```

Comment: Is that your GET or POST? You need to pass the viewmodel into the view() of the GET. https://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/28/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-1-view-model-binding/

Comment: The code you have shown binds fine assuming that is the POST method and has the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: It is a post Method, as I said I was able to pull values using a non POCO.

Comment: If you are having some subtle problem, you may need to post all the applicable code (GET, POST, View). If that is the POST, it should be checking ModelState and only returning the View on error.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the method.it is post. and I'm using modelview model, the mvvm is where my dal model and view model are compiled. i'll test some more..otherwise I might just end up using a non-poco to use as a Name value.